# ValidationSummary in MVC Razor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a strongly typed form which uses `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` to output a validation message next to the form field e.g. `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comment)`. This works great.

I would like to add a validation Summary directly above the submit button that outputs a list of errors as a ul. However, using `@Html.ValidationSummary();` causes two issues.

**Issue 1**
It outputs the validation message like so

[image]

I would like it to list each individual error for example

- Name is required
- Comment is required

**Issue 2**
When the validation is triggered i am no longer able to do a post by re-selecting the submit button once i have rectified the validation errors?

Here is a cut down version of my form

```
@using System.Linq
@using System.Web

@model MyProject.Models.ViewModels.Forms.ContactViewModel
<div class="form-block">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>1. Your details</legend>
            <div>
                <div>
                    @Html.RequiredLabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder = "First name" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                </div>
            </div>          
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit feedback"/>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationSummary();
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me how to get around this?

Thanks

Edit * Ok i have disabled javascript and using @Html.ValidationSummary() with server side posts works ok. The validation message is displayed for the form field that failed. How can i update the default client side message to list each validation error message.

Comment: Have you tried @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

Comment: Yes, sorry i should have mentioned that i tried that but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Check your ModelStateDictionary object in the post method of the controller - the Html.ValidationSummary() method returns a html UL based on the errors that are present in there.